# Setting values of flag with find statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on an angular app. In my code I have to find a element from array and set value of  the flag. My code is as follows

```
 myId = this.Names.find(id => id === '1');
```

So, from Names array I am checking id. If id is 1 I need to set a flag myFlag to true. I know I can use if else statement after this. But instead of if else, I want to do it more efficiently. Is there is any way by which I can set myFlag directly from find statement.

Comment: In general, you can use `.some()` instead, this will return the boolean value you're looking for. `const myFlag = this.Names.some(id => id === '1');`. In this case you can simply use `.includes()` though: `const myFlag = this.Names.includes('1');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` will return `undefined` if it cant find anything, so you could do this:

```
const myFlag = !myId; // Sets to true if nothing is found
const myFlag = !!myId; // Sets to false if nothing is found
```

You could also check out [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), but that doesnt return the id:

```
const myFlag = this.Names.some(id => id === '1'); // If it finds an id with 1, sets to true. Otherwise, false
```

These are used for an array of objects, so if your array only has strings, you could just use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const myFlag = this.Names.includes('1'); // If it finds an id with 1, sets to true. Otherwise, false
```

Comment: my vscode not showing option of some. How I can get it?

Comment: as in my model name is of type any. when I make it to array by Name? : [] , it runs the code but gives error  A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

Comment: Try `Name?: string[]` (so an array of strings). Or `Name?: any[]` (an array of anythings)